# PostgreSQL With vs SubQuery

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, optimization, query-optimization

I have these two queries with similar `Query Plan` outputs:

```
update cartfund A
set "CartId" = (select id from cart where "UserId" = 6)
from cart B
where A."CartId" = B.id and
B."GuestUserId" = 1139;
```

Query Plan for above:

```
Update on cartfund a  (cost=16.61..44.36 rows=1 width=43)
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Index Scan using "cart_UserId_key" on cart  (cost=0.28..8.30 rows=1 width=4)
           Index Cond: ("UserId" = 6)
   ->  Hash Join  (cost=8.31..36.06 rows=1 width=43)
         Hash Cond: (a."CartId" = b.id)
         ->  Seq Scan on cartfund a  (cost=0.00..22.90 rows=1290 width=41)
         ->  Hash  (cost=8.30..8.30 rows=1 width=10)
               ->  Index Scan using "cart_GuestUserId_key" on cart b  (cost=0.28..8.30 rows=1 width=10)
                     Index Cond: ("GuestUserId" = 1139)
```

Similarly this query does the same task:

```
with usercart as (select id from cart where "UserId" = 6)
update cartfund a
set "CartId" = c.id
from cart b, usercart c
where a."CartId" = b.id and
b."GuestUserId" = 1139;
```

And has this query plan:

```
Update on cartfund a  (cost=16.61..44.39 rows=1 width=75)
   CTE usercart
     ->  Index Scan using "cart_UserId_key" on cart  (cost=0.28..8.30 rows=1 width=4)
           Index Cond: ("UserId" = 6)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=8.31..36.09 rows=1 width=75)
         ->  Hash Join  (cost=8.31..36.06 rows=1 width=43)
               Hash Cond: (a."CartId" = b.id)
               ->  Seq Scan on cartfund a  (cost=0.00..22.90 rows=1290 width=41)
               ->  Hash  (cost=8.30..8.30 rows=1 width=10)
                     ->  Index Scan using "cart_GuestUserId_key" on cart b  (cost=0.28..8.30 rows=1 width=10)
                           Index Cond: ("GuestUserId" = 1139)
         ->  CTE Scan on usercart c  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=32)
```

Which one should I use? What are the performance trade-offs? Thanks.

Comment: If I read correctly, these two queries aren't even doing the same thing logically.  The second one involves a table `usercart` which isn't present in the first.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen usercart is an alias for subquery `(select id from cart where "UserId" = 6)`

Comment: I think it does not mater. The only thing which is strage in this update is the (select id from cart where "UserId" = 6) part. Is this valu gona change? If the "UserId" = 6 and the "GuestUserId" = 1139 is hard coded why dont you hard code the id too?

Comment: @PeterRing Thanks. Yes, the values will change. They'll be provided by the app code. Are you sure about both the queries being the same ?

Comment: WITH is a barrier for the optimizer, sometimes it is better than a subquery sometimes not :)